# Spark: adding column name to csv file fails

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have "a.txt" which is in csv format and is separated by tabs:

```
16777216    16777471        -33.4940    143.2104
16777472    16778239    Fuzhou  26.0614 119.3061
```

Then I run:

```
sc.textFile("path/to/a.txt").map(line => line.split("\t")).toDF("startIP", "endIP", "City", "Longitude", "Latitude")
```

THen I got:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of
>   columns doesn't match. Old column names (1): value New column names
>   (5): startIP, endIP, City, Longitude, Latitude   at
>   scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toDF(Dataset.scala:376)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder.toDF(DatasetHolder.scala:40)   ...
>   47 elided

If I just run:

```
res.map(line => line.split("\t")).take(2)
```

I got:

```
rdd: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(16777216, 16777471, "", -33.4940, 143.2104), Array(16777472, 16778239, Fuzhou, 26.0614, 119.3061))
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user7881163 notes, the error occurs because your `split` produces a single column whose value (hence the `value` name given by Spark) is the array of tokens produced by the `split`.

However, per comments from @zero323, just make sure you use the version of `collect` @user7881163 uses (the one that takes a partial function) if you are operating at scale because the other, far more commonly used `collect` will move all your data to the driver and overwhelm that machine. And if you aren't operating at scale, why use Spark at all?

This is a slightly different approach that also allows for missing city data:

```
sc.textFile("path/to/a.txt")
  .map(_.split("\t"))
  .map {
      case Array(startIP, endIP, city, longitude, latitude) => (startIP, endIP, Some(city), longitude, latitude)
      case Array(startIP, endIP, longitude, latitude) => (startIP, endIP, None, longitude, latitude)
  }.toDF("startIP", "endIP", "City", "Longitude", "Latitude")
```

Comment: `collect` transformation doesn't move any data to the driver. Also making pattern match exhaustive would be a good idea.

Comment: First, as noted in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions), `collect` is an *action*--not a transformation, which matters--that does this: "*Return all the elements of the dataset as an array at the driver program. This is usually useful after a filter or other operation that returns a sufficiently small subset of the data.*" That would be bad at scale as noted.

Comment: Second, yes, pattern matches should be exhaustive. It didn't occur to me to veer outside the scope of the question to "Scala best practices"; maybe I should have. I only accounted for the data formats @derek indicated. So yeah, @derek, if you take this approach, make your pattern match exhaustive or manage exceptions properly with logging, `Try`, etc.

Comment: You're not talking about the same `collect` :) https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3755da76c3821e8e6a4f359c43243a51a06559ca/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L956-L962 which is equivalent of [`Seq.collect`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Seq[B]) in the Scala collection API.

Comment: Ahh OK. I have never seen that version of `collect` anywhere, but yes, that does keep things distributed. I've edited accordingly. Of course, this whole point isn't really germane to the question, and it would've been more aligned with Stack Overflow guidelines to simply edit the answer to make it better than engage in a long comment thread on a topic that isn't even essential to the question about the shape of the data being ingested.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sc
  .textFile("path/to/a.txt")
  .map(line => line.split("\t"))
  .collect { case Array(startIP, endIP, City, Longitude, Latitude) => 
    (startIP, endIP, City, Longitude, Latitude) 
  }.toDF("startIP", "endIP", "City", "Longitude", "Latitude")
```

or just use `csv` source:

```
spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv("path/to/a.txt")
```

Your current code creates a `DataFrame` with a single column of type `array<string>`. This is why it fails when you pass 5 names.

Comment: This should be `{case Array(...) => ... }` not `{case Seq(...) => ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example:

```
dataDF = sc.textFile("filepath").map(x=>x.split('\t').toDF();

data = dataDF.selectExpr("_1 as startIP", "_2 as endIP", "_3 as City", "_4 as Longitude", "_5 as Latitude");
```