# Programmatically add column names to Spark DataFrame built from an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I’ve got a pipe-delimited textfile without a header, and the rows have different numbers of columns (some rows are type `A` with 400 columns, others type `B` with 200, so I need to separate them first):

```
val textFileRaw = sc.textFile("./data.txt")
val textFile = textFileRaw.map(line => line.split("\\|", -1))
val dataA = textFile.filter(line => line(0) == "A")
val dataB = textFile.filter(line => line(0) == "B")
```

Now I'd like to convert these RDD's into Spark DataFrames, but the split is returning a single array, rather than 400 or 200 distinct values. This results in the following error:

```
# ANames are my column names, length=400
val ANames = Array("Row ID", "City", "State", ...)
val dataADF = dataA.toDF(ANames: _*)

Name: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (1): value
New column names (400): Row ID, City, State ...
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461342/spark-adding-column-name-to-csv-file-fails) faces the same problem, but all the answers suggest manually specifying a mapping from array to Tuple, which isn't great in the case with hundreds of columns.

I think I could get it to work if I used [Spark's csv loader](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html), but this doesn't work for my data because the rows have different number of fields (it's not a true csv file). A work-around would be to first split the files, write new files that are well-formed csv's, and then use the csv loader, but  I'd like to avoid this if possible. How can I convert these RDD's into DataFrames with named columns?

Comment: All you have to do is put the 400 columns data at the top of the file at least one and then use sqlContext api to read the data into dataframes and change the header names and datatypes later on. Thats all I guess

Comment: Some rows in the datafile are 200 different columns, however

Comment: if you can modify the text file so that 400 columns data comes first then null will be placed where insufficient fields are read in 200 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be creating a schema and use SQLContext.createDataFrame api as

```
val dataA = textFile.filter(line => line(0) == "A")
val ANames = Array("Row ID", "City", "State", "kjl")
val dataADF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataA.map(Row.fromSeq(_)), StructType(ANames.map(StructField(_, StringType, true))))
```

It should work . But to note that I have used all *data types* as `StringType()`. You can change according to your need.

Comment: As you say, the `Array[String]` is one object, and that's what the `split` returns. Without the `Seq`, it's still an RDD with a single column of `Array[String]`, and the same error is raised. I accidentally put the `Seq` in when I was testing possible solutions

Comment: Yes you are right @KyleHeuton, I have update my answer for next solution i.e. by creating a schema

Comment: It works! I wish I could use some of SparkSession's `inferSchema`'s abilities here, but this might be the best I can do with the data the way it is. The best solution might be to split the data, as you've said. I'll accept this answer in a day or so if nothing else amazing comes in

Comment: can you adjust your data as I said in my comments in the question so that 400 columns data comes in the pipe delimited file. If yes then you can try as I already said :)

Comment: are 200 column names the same for both ?

Comment: The other 200 columns are completely different, I think you would have to split the data into 2 separate text files like I said in my question

Comment: yes that would be the best to separate them as the columns are different